# Adding a Storage Tier to an existing Virtual Disk in Storage Spaces

Tags: windows-10, storage-spaces

I've got an existing and working (I think) Storage Space on my machine. It is tiered - it has SSD and HDD's in it:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-StorageTier

FriendlyName     TierClass   MediaType ResiliencySettingName FaultDomainRedundancy   Size FootprintOnPool StorageEfficiency
------------     ---------   --------- --------------------- ---------------------   ---- --------------- -----------------
SSD              Unknown     SSD       Mirror                1                       0 B             0 B
Onedrive-HDD     Capacity    HDD       Simple                0                       1 TB            1 TB           100.00%
Onedrive-SSD     Performance SSD       Simple                0                      50 GB           50 GB           100.00%
AppsAndUsers-SSD Performance SSD       Simple                0                     100 GB          100 GB           100.00%
AppsAndUsers-HDD Capacity    HDD       Simple                0                     500 GB          500 GB           100.00%
HDD              Unknown     HDD       Mirror                1                       0 B             0 B
GRID2-HDD        Capacity    HDD       Simple                0                       1 TB            1 TB           100.00%
```

That last one - GRID2 - is bursting at the seems and also has about 300 GB of hot data on it.

I've recently upgraded with some new SSD's and HDD's. As a result I'd like to add the SSD tier to that virtual disk, and also resize the existing tier up to about 4 TB. I think I know how to resize it using `Set-StorageTier`, but looking at the web and documentation I can't figure out how to add a new storage tier to an existing virtual disk.

Is there a way, or do I need to create a new virtual disk with the proper tiers in the first place? Note this isn't S2D.